# Templating a Snippet with $modx->getChunk returns nothing

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution

Hi I'm stuck with this output, please suggest what's wrong:

```
$responsexml = @simplexml_load_string($result, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA | LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
foreach ($responsexml as $hotelresponse)
 {
    $hotelname = ($hotelresponse->HotelInfo->Name);
    $hoteldestination = ($hotelresponse->HotelInfo->Destination->Name);
    $hotelcategory = ($hotelresponse->HotelInfo->Category);
    $hotelimage = ($hotelresponse->HotelInfo->ImageList->Image[0]->Url);

    $returnedoutput .= $modx->getChunk('_testxmlchunk',array(
        'hotel' => $hotelname,
        'destination' => $hoteldestination,
        'category' => $hotelcategory,
        'image' => $hotelimage,
    ));
      }

return $returnedoutput;
```

_testxmlchunk chunk template:

```
<li>this is <b>[[+hotel]]</b> is in <b>[[+destination]]</b> category <b>[[+category]]</b> pic <img src="[[+image]]"/></li>
```

It returns only the blank chunk template

this is  is in  category  pic

but when I do the following.. it works

```
$responsexml = @simplexml_load_string($result, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA | LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
foreach ($responsexml as $hotelresponse)
 {
    $hotelname = ($hotelresponse->HotelInfo->Name);
    $hoteldestination = ($hotelresponse->HotelInfo->Destination->Name);
    $hotelcategory = ($hotelresponse->HotelInfo->Category);
    $hotelimage = ($hotelresponse->HotelInfo->ImageList->Image[0]->Url);

    $returnedoutput .= $hotelname.' '.$hotelimage.' '. $hoteldestination.' '.$hotelcategory.';
     }

return $returnedoutput;
```

any suggestion... Did I miss something? I want to template my snippet.

I use:
MODX Revolution 2.2.10-pl (advanced)
mysql 5.5.37-35.0
PHP Version 5.4.29

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to call `setPlaceholder`, you should be able to pass the placeholders directly to the chunk as you've already attempted.

I'm not sure why you are setting the `$hotelresponse` properties into variables, or why you have the properties themselves wrapped in brackets. But your code can be simplified to the following:

```
$returnedoutput = '';

$responsexml = @simplexml_load_string($result, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA | LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
foreach ($responsexml as $hotelresponse) {
    $returnedoutput .= $modx->getChunk('_testxmlchunk', array(
        'hotel' => $hotelresponse->HotelInfo->Name,
        'destination' => $hotelresponse->HotelInfo->Destination->Name,
        'category' => $hotelresponse->HotelInfo->Category,
        'image' => $hotelresponse->HotelInfo->ImageList->Image[0]->Url,
    ));
}

return $returnedoutput;
```

I would expect that to work, if the `HotelInfo` object is valid.

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work..I found that I should set the placeholder Or I should cast the object into string, eg: 'hotel' => $hotelresponse->(string)HotelInfo->Name,.....

Comment: I insist that this *is* the way it should be done, there is no need to set a placeholder. `var_dump()` your `HotelInfo` object to see how the properties are cast, and if necessary you would cast to string like this: `'hotel' => (string) $hotelresponse->HotelInfo->Name`

Answer (score 0):

**I found the solution (SOLVED):**
I should set the placeholder right before

```
$returnedoutput .= $modx->getChunk('_testxmlchunk',array(
        'hotel' => $hotelname,
        'destination' => $hoteldestination,
        'category' => $hotelcategory,
        'image' => $hotelimage,
    ));
```

Or the alternative way is by convert the object variable type into string without setting the placeholder:

```
$returnedoutput .= $modx->getChunk('_testxmlchunk',array(
'hotel' => (string)$hotelname,
'destination' => (string)$hoteldestination,
'category' => (string)$hotelcategory,
'image' => (string)$hotelimage,
));
```

Here is **the correct answer**:

```
$responsexml = @simplexml_load_string($result, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA | LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
foreach ($responsexml as $hotelresponse)
 {
    $hotelname = ($hotelresponse->HotelInfo->Name);
    $hoteldestination = ($hotelresponse->HotelInfo->Destination->Name);
    $hotelcategory = ($hotelresponse->HotelInfo->Category);
    $hotelimage = ($hotelresponse->HotelInfo->ImageList->Image[0]->Url);


    $modx->setPlaceholder('hotel',$hotelname);
    $modx->setPlaceholder('destination',$hoteldestination);
    $modx->setPlaceholder('category',$hotelcategory);
    $modx->setPlaceholder('image',$hotelimage);

    $returnedoutput .= $modx->getChunk('_testxmlchunk',array(
        'hotel' => $hotelname,
        'destination' => $hoteldestination,
        'category' => $hotelcategory,
        'image' => $hotelimage,
    ));


  }
return $returnedoutput;
```

Here is **the correct answer 2 (alternative)**:

```
$responsexml = @simplexml_load_string($result, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA | LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
foreach ($responsexml as $hotelresponse)
 {
    $hotelname = ($hotelresponse->HotelInfo->Name);
    $hoteldestination = ($hotelresponse->HotelInfo->Destination->Name);
    $hotelcategory = ($hotelresponse->HotelInfo->Category);
    $hotelimage = ($hotelresponse->HotelInfo->ImageList->Image[0]->Url);

            /***
             cast the xml object into string, $hotelname variable type is object, you should convert it to string
            ***/
    $returnedoutput .= $modx->getChunk('_testxmlchunk',array(
        'hotel' => (string)$hotelname,
        'destination' => (string)$hoteldestination,
        'category' => (string)$hotelcategory,
        'image' => (string)$hotelimage,
    ));


  }
return $returnedoutput;
```

Comment: That might work, but it's not really the correct way to do it. Just passing the placeholder array to `getChunk()` as you have already done should work. See my answer below.